# Explaining the harmony of Wagner's Wanderer motif

Tags: theory, harmony, terminology, chord-progressions, modulation

Recently I listened to the Wanderer leitmotif from Wagner's Ring cycle. I was both impressed and perplexed by the motif's harmony. The picture below tries to explain the possible modulations that this motif implies. It's quite pedantic, since I think most perfect cadences weren't necessary, but I wanted to establish the tonality and then modulate to a new key center.

The Wanderer motif: [Wagner - Wanderer motif](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drFY8HusgrA)

and the short piece I wrote:

[image]

Explanation of symbols:

- +M is the *Medianté* (is it called chromatic mediant in English?), i.e. the III degree chord of a major scale with a major third (e.g., the +M of C major is E major),
- oTr is the chord that's relative (r) to T minor (o=minor and T=tonic). To explain it more accurately, the oTr chord of D (major or minor) is F major.
- oSr is the same as oTr, where S stands for subdominant. For example, the oSr chord of C (major or minor) is Ab major, i.e., the relative key of F minor (IV of C minor).

Lastly, as I haven't found the above symbols elsewhere except in my Harmony textbook: are there any equivalent symbols to describe these chords in the international music bibliography?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting exercise!

I see two questions in your text:

> "is it called chromatic mediant in English?"

Yes; although the term "chromatic mediant" can mean a few chords, this chord would be one of them. Some theorists (like [David Kopp](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/chromatic-transformations-in-nineteenth-century-music/23DDA64171C8B60F88D4F47AB4604DF3)) would call this an "upper sharp mediant," because it's the chord built on the upper mediant and it involves raising pitches.

> "are there any equivalent symbols to describe these chords in the international music bibliography?"

You're using Riemannian function labels, which should be understood by someone in academic music theory. But a non-academic in America almost certainly wouldn't recognize them. If you want a more universal system that others will understand, I would recommend using Roman numerals for most of these chords. The B major chord in m. 3, for instance, would be III♯, because it's built on scale-degree 3 (hence III), and the ♯ shows that you raise the chordal third to D♯, thus making it major. The B♭ chord in m. 9, since you're in D major, would be ♭VI6: ♭VI because it's built on the lowered scale-degree 6 in D, and 6 because it's in first inversion.

Comment: After reading stevtomato's comment on the YouTube video, I think the most easy way to understand how it works is the following: First two bars are in A major, the rest are in G major. The sequence has this chord progression: V/V -> IV -> II Neap. -> V. Thus, between the first and the last chord, the music "wanders", since it doesn't go straight from V/V to V. And the whole "magical sound" of this motif is maybe due to the false relation between the D# in the bass on the first chord and the D in the upper voice on the second chord.